# Reflection Initialize Property Values of an object Instance Using

Tags: c#, reflection

I have an Object instance. In the Object's Constructor, I would like to allow user to pass in a Dictionary with which to initialize, some, if not all of the properties of the object. Now, instead of using a conditional, what I would like to do is using reflection, reflect over the properties contained in the object instance, and if the property name, maps to a key in the dictionary, update the property value with the corresponding value in the Dictionary.

In working on this, I have the following code, but it does not update the value of my object instance. Would appreciate some help getting this to work please?

```
 public void Initialize()
        {
            if (Report.GlobalParameters != null)
            {
                PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = this.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
                {
                    if (Report.GlobalParameters.ContainsKey(propertyInfo.Name))
                    {
                        Type type = this.GetType();
                        PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
                        property.SetValue(this, Report.GlobalParameters[propertyInfo.Name], null);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Sample of the object would be nice (just on property that shows "does not update the value of my object instance"). It also may be good idea to simplify sample in post to use hard-coded name and value.

Comment: I have tried your code on a Person object i created and it works well, no problems at all ?!!

Comment: Thanks, I checked and it seems to work fine now. Not sure what I changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, have you attached a debugger to inspect whether or not you're getting inside the most nested `if`? And if you're not getting inside the most nested `if`, can you figure out why by comparing what you expect to be happening to what is actually happening when you inspect in the debugger?

Second, inside the most nested `if`, you can remove the first two lines, and replace `property` with `propertyInfo` in the third line (which will be the only line remaining when you remove the first two). You already have the `PropertyInfo` with the given name in hand, why are you looking it up again?

Beyond that, it *looks* like what you have should work. Thus, there error lies elsewhere, meaning you aren't passing in the right values, or something else that you're not telling us about is going on.

Here is a [small *working* example](http://ideone.com/5hSxTA) of what you have that should help you:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Foo {
    public int Bar { get; set; }
    public Foo(Dictionary<string, object> values) {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach(var property in propertyInfo) {
            if(values.ContainsKey(property.Name)) {
                property.SetValue(this, values[property.Name], null);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Program {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Dictionary<string, object> values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        values.Add("Bar", 42);
        Foo foo = new Foo(values);
        Console.WriteLine(foo.Bar); // expect 42
    }
}
```

Notice that it's exactly your logic and it [*works*](http://ideone.com/5hSxTA). Does this help?

Answer (score -1):

Does it work any better if you switch it up and do?

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        if (Report.GlobalParameters != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in Report.GlobalParameters)
            {
                PropertyInfo pi = this.GetType().GetProperty(kvp.Key, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (pi != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        pi.SetValue(this, kvp.Value, null);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(kvp.Key + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(), "Error Setting Property Value");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(kvp.Key, "Property Not Found");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```